# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 whem compiling a C++ program using g++

Tags: c++, macos, makefile, new-operator

The problem happens when I use "new" to define an array of size n when the n will be read-in when the program runs:  x=new double[n];
If I delete the above line of code the program compiles successfully.
I was told that I did not make any mistake in the grammar and the code can compile successfully using VC. I use mac and I suspect that this is due to the makefile so I put the error message and the makefile here. Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks.

```
client-104-39-60-181:~/Desktop/Desttop/work/C_programing/Test_6_21_2016]make
g++ -Wall   -W -g -std=c++14 -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/GL -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/X11R6/include/GL main.cpp -c -o main.o
g++ -Wall   -W -g -std=c++14 -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/GL -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/X11R6/include/GL mytest.cpp -c -o mytest.o
g++ -Wall   -W -g -std=c++14 -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/GL -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/X11R6/include/GL run_Lorenz96.cpp -c -o run_Lorenz96.o
g++ main.o mytest.o run_Lorenz96.o -L/usr/lib -L/usr/X11R6/lib -L/usr/local/lib -lX11 -lGL -lGLU -lglut -lcblas -lclapack -o run
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "___cxa_throw_bad_array_new_length", referenced from:
      run_Lorenz96::init()      in run_Lorenz96.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [run] Error 1
```

The makefile:

```
NAME        = run
CC      = g++
SRC     = main.cpp mytest.cpp run_Lorenz96.cpp
CFLAGS      = -Wall -W -g -std=c++14

IFLAGS= -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/GL -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/X11R6/include/GL

LFLAGS= -L/usr/lib -L/usr/X11R6/lib -L/usr/local/lib -lX11 -lGL -lGLU -lglut -lcblas -lclapack

OBJ   = $(SRC:.cpp=.o)

all :       $(NAME)

$(NAME) :   $(OBJ)
        $(CC) $(OBJ) $(LFLAGS) -o $(NAME)

.cpp.o : 
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(IFLAGS) $< -c -o $@

clean :
        $(RM) $(OBJ)
        $(RM) $(NAME)
```

The following is a minimal example which gives the same kind of error message:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
#include<vector>
#include<lapacke.h>


using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n;
    double* x;

    n=10;
    x=new double[n];

    return 0;

}
```

The output of g++ -v is the following:

```
client-104-39-60-181:~/Desktop/Desttop/work/C_programing/Test_6_23_2016]g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/opt/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13/5.4.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13
Configured with: /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_mports_dports_lang_gcc5/gcc5/work/gcc-5.4.0/configure --prefix=/opt/local --build=x86_64-apple-darwin13 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,lto,fortran,java --libdir=/opt/local/lib/gcc5 --includedir=/opt/local/include/gcc5 --infodir=/opt/local/share/info --mandir=/opt/local/share/man --datarootdir=/opt/local/share/gcc-5 --with-local-prefix=/opt/local --with-system-zlib --disable-nls --program-suffix=-mp-5 --with-gxx-include-dir=/opt/local/include/gcc5/c++/ --with-gmp=/opt/local --with-mpfr=/opt/local --with-mpc=/opt/local --with-isl=/opt/local --enable-stage1-checking --disable-multilib --enable-lto --enable-libstdcxx-time --with-build-config=bootstrap-debug --with-as=/opt/local/bin/as --with-ld=/opt/local/bin/ld --with-ar=/opt/local/bin/ar --with-bugurl=https://trac.macports.org/newticket --with-pkgversion='MacPorts gcc5 5.4.0_0'
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.4.0 (MacPorts gcc5 5.4.0_0)
```

The output of which g++ is the following:

```
client-104-39-60-181:~/Desktop/Desttop/work/C_programing/Test_6_23_2016]which g++
/opt/local/bin/g++
```

Comment: Can you also include in your question the commands and error message(s) that get emitted when you do `make -B` ?

Comment: If you have a suspicion, verify that instead of asking off-topic questions (minimal but complete example is missing).

Comment: @PaulR It has been added.

Comment: Which g++ are you using ? The one that is linked to clang++ (which gets installed with Xcode) or a third party g++ (Homebrew et al) ?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt the minimal example has been added.

Comment: @PaulR How to check which g++ is it?

Comment: Do a `which g++` and also `g++ -v`.

Comment: @PaulR This information has been added.

Comment: OK - it looks like you are using MacPorts g++ 5.4.0 for some reason - maybe you installed it at some time in the past to get C++14 support ? (BTW, do you actually need C++14 support or can you make do with C++11 ?)

Comment: @PaulR Do you mean my g++ does not recognize C++14? Should I update my g++?

Comment: No, I meant that there may be an issue with library support for C++14 with your MacPorts version of g++. You might want to do an update though (I think it's something like `port selfupdate` first and then `port upgrade g++` or something like that - I switched to Homebrew a long time ago so I'm not too familiar with MacPorts any more).

Comment: @PaulR I just changed C++14 to C++11. gcc5.4 should be later than C++11, but the error still exists.

Comment: OK - I'm out of ideas then - your makefile and build commands look OK, but since you're using MacPorts I don't know what to suggest. You might be better off with Apple's developer tools and/or Homebrew, but that will take some time to set up. Maybe someone else with some knowledge of MacPorts can help.

Comment: @PaulR Thanks as well.

Comment: If you compile the file on its own with the commands that make uses, does it happen? If yes, the makefile isn't the problem and you could remove it from your question. Then, how about the lapack stuff? What if you remove that? Also, is it a C++ library? If yes, it may be that it was compiled with a different compiler, which can cause it to be incompatible with your compiler. In some cases, even the version of the compiler and commandline arguments can make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem would seem to be that you're getting the wrong libstdc++ version for the version of g++ that you are using.  Best guess is that it is coming from the `-L/usr/lib` or `-L/usr/local/lib` options that you are explicitly adding to the link command line (where they will be searched before any built-in directories), so try removing them from `LFLAGS` (they should be searched by default, but after any compiler-specific directories).  If that doesn't work, try adding `-L/opt/local/lib` to LFLAGS, or search in `/opt/local` for `libstdc++.*` and link it explicitly.

Comment: But I don't get any error if I delete the line: x=new double[n];

Comment: Linking the wrong GNU libstdc++ version will actually work in *most* cases -- the incompatibilities between g++ versions are only in a few corner cases, so you're apparently only hitting one when that line is present.